# Detecting incoming calls with CallKit when the app is in background

Tags: ios, swift4, callkit

I'm trying to detect incoming calls with my app using CallKit, But it is not working when the app enters background. Is there any way to detect the incoming calls when the apps goes background. Also tried with notificationcenter but it is not working properly.

Here is the code I referred .

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(cameFromBackground),
            name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationWillResignActive,
            object: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        print("Call Status - ", phoneCallStatus())
        switch phoneCallStatus()
        {
        case true:
            print("Incomming")
        case false:
            print("OnGoing")
            default: break
        }
    }

    @objc private func phoneCallStatus() -> Bool
    {
        let callCntr = CXCallObserver()
        let calls = callCntr.calls

        for call in calls{
            if call.isOutgoing == false  {
                print("Incomming")
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }

    @objc func cameFromBackground()
    {
        self.viewWillAppear(true)
    }
```

Comment: If your app is a voip app then you can detect incoming calls on your voip service,  it if you are asking about incoming calls in general, then no, there is no way to be notified about incoming calls if your app isn't in the foreground.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: As per our requirement we don't have VOIP. So I have not proceed after this. Thanks

Comment: @Paulw11 Is there any documentation for proving that this requirement can not be fulfilled?  I am building an app that needs to send some command to a BLE device when there is an incoming phone call and that the app can be in background when that happened. Thank you,

Comment: I don’t know about documentation that explicitly states that something can’t be done. What is documented is what *can* be done, in particular the available background capabilities that an app can have. General CallKit callbacks isn’t one (VoIP push is a specific case)